# Basic python coding

Tags: python

Trying to do a simple guessing game program in python, but I'm more comfortable in java.
When the correct number is entered, it says it is too high and won't exit the while loop.
Any suggestions?

```
import random
comp_num = random.randint(1,101)
print comp_num
players_guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ")
while players_guess != comp_num:
    if players_guess > comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too high!"
    elif players_guess < comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too low!"
    players_guess = raw_input("Guess another number between 1 and 100: ")
print "CONGRATULATIONS! YOU GUESSED CORRECTLY!"
```

Comment: Use `elif` for the second `if`...

Comment: still only outputs too high...

Comment: it is not a good idea to keep updating your question to reflect the answers (even if the answers are correct). It makes the answers look irrelevant, and removes any chance of other learning from your errors.

Comment: Some IDEs like PyCharm come with a handy debugger. Saves time asking questions online.

Answer (score 8):

I would guess it is because you are comparing `string` and `int`. Whatever is captured from `raw_input` is captured as a `string` and, in Python:

```py
print "1" > 100    # Will print true
```

For it to work, convert:

```
players_guess = raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ")
```

to

```
players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
```

Comment: thanks, guys! but it still won't exit the while loop once I enter the right number..

Comment: Or perhaps you forgot to cast your second `raw_input` to an `int`... like your updated question indicates. You should not update your question with answers, since you're only confusing things.

Comment: @MaxRegitnig like maksimov says, you probably forgot to cast your second `raw_input` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: or just make  100  a string

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of dynamic typing. You'll learn to love it as much as hate it.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a string to an int. That's why you get odd results.

Try this:

```
players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
comp_num = random.randint(1,101)
print comp_num
players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
while players_guess != comp_num:
    if players_guess > comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too high!"
    elif players_guess < comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too low!"
   players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number between 1 and 100: "))
print "CONGRATULATIONS! YOU GUESSED CORRECTLY!"
```

you need to force the input to int

Comment: you missed the int from the 2nd raw_input call.

Comment: yea it was a typing mistake, down voting is not a soln

Comment: for what it is worth - I didn't downvote, I just stated a reason why someone might have done so - it does seem a little harsh to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import random
comp_num = random.randint(1,101)
print comp_num
players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
while players_guess != comp_num:
    if players_guess > comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too high!"
    elif players_guess < comp_num:
        print "Your guess is too low!"
    players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number between 1 and 100: "))
print "CONGRATULATIONS! YOU GUESSED CORRECTLY!"
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

in your code change in print formation and use 'int' datatype in numerical argument. i will change the cond so try it once:

```
    import random
comp_num = random.randint(1,101)
print ('comp_num')
players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
while players_guess != comp_num:
    if players_guess > comp_num:
        print('Your guess is too high!')
    elif players_guess < comp_num:
        print('Your guess is too low!')
    players_guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number between 1 and 100: "))
print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU GUESSED CORRECTLY!')
```